# Reason for "not rounded" window height for Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser

Using `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`, I found that my chrome window size is 1440px * 749px. My question is, why the number 749? This is also the number I get using `document.documentElement.clientHeight`.

I found "749px" appearing in some other CSS media query questions, but I can't find anyone talking about WHY we use/get values like 749 or 549. Can't they be rounded up to something like 750 or 550?

Comment: Probably it's 749px because it should be 900px-(your chrome upper bar size in px) assuming that your aspect ratio and resolution are 1440px*900px  . This sizes are related to your screen resolution and innerHeight gives you the height of the "printable" area. Probably they choose to use that extra pixel in order to prevent some strange overlappings.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more context? For example, what device and OS are you using and have you changed the viewport in any way (e.g. some resizing).

Comment: The data was obtained on my laptop (ASUS Vivobook X1403za) running Windows 11 with screen dimension of 2880*1800 (I would assume a 1:2 CSS px to device px), and no, I haven't changed the viewport in any way(i.e, zoom on 100%).

Comment: What do you get in full screen mode?

Comment: @AHaworth Exactly 1440*900.